# how to bind the values in to list view and table view in nokia qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia

I have to bind the list of array values in to list view or table view. Can any one say with example web link? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you question is rather vague, al I can say is: read up on [Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html). It will explain how to get your data in a QListView or QTableView.